# R: Less calculation intensive way of calculating distance between long/lat and a shape file

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a shape file of US Coast lines from [NOAA Shoreline Website](https://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/medres.html)

and have a data frame containing longitude and latitude coordinates. I need to quickly calculate the minimum distance between them. However, the current method I have takes about 30 seconds to calculate per coordinate.

```
require(geospehere)
require(rgdal)

data.sf <- my.coordinates %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('Longitude','Latitude')) %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326)

shape <- read_sf("/us_medium_shoreline.shp")

dist <- geosphere::dist2Line(p = st_coordinates(data.sf), 
                             line = st_coordinates(shape$geometry)[,1:2])
```

The shape files also come in formats .avl, .dbf, .shx, .prj, and .shx, but I'm not sure how to use them properly.

Comment: Is `sf::st_distance(data.sf, shape)` any faster?

Comment: @CalumYou, I get the error "st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE"

Comment: Transform them to the same crs?

Comment: Not even sure how to do that with the read_sf

Comment: use `st_transform`

Comment: Could you share the dataframe of lat/long coordinates?

Comment: @agila, I'm making it into an API, so I've just been using (-81,26) as a test coordinate